When is the long exact sequence of sheaf cohomology a series of many short exact sequences
Let $0\rightarrow \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C \rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules on a (say projective, normal) scheme $X$. Taking sheaf cohomology induces a long exact sequence. What are commonly known conditions for the long exact sequence to be a series of short exact sequences, i.e.
$$ 0 \rightarrow H^i(X,\mathcal A) \rightarrow H^i(X,\mathcal B) \rightarrow H^i(X,\mathcal C) \rightarrow 0$$
to be exact for all $i$?
One obvious example would be for the short exact sequence to be split.

I believe being split is the only reasonable condition that will cause this to happen. In fact, the sequence is split if and only if
$$ 0 \rightarrow Hom(C,A) \rightarrow Hom(C,B) \rightarrow Hom(C,C) \rightarrow 0 $$
is exact. I realize your question is about the functor $\Gamma(X,_)$ and not $Hom(C,_)$ but hopefully this helps.
